# Rails HTTP request raises `EOFError: end of file reached` after some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Rails apps that are communicating through HTTP.

The app that is supposed to receive requests takes a long time to respond. I expect that, so using my preferred request method (provided by the `httparty` gem) I increase the timeout and submit the request:

```
HTTParty.get("https://example.com", :timeout => 99999)
```

After approx. 2 minutes the error `EOFError: end of file reached` is raised by the requesting app, with the following stack trace:

```
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1414:in `block in transport_request'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1377:in `block in request'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/httparty-0.13.7/lib/httparty/request.rb:117:in `perform'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/httparty-0.13.7/lib/httparty.rb:545:in `perform_request'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/httparty-0.13.7/lib/httparty.rb:476:in `get'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/httparty-0.13.7/lib/httparty.rb:583:in `get'
from (irb):14
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

But in the log of my receiving app I can see that the request is still being processed. So the requesing app must be raising the exception based on something else that a response.

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Given you've set the timeout to 9999, but it's still timing out after approx 2 minutes, it sounds like the server you're requesting data from is throwing a timeout, causing the EOF error.

Comment: Hi @tombeynon but can that be possible when I see in my receivers server log that it's still processing the request when the requesing app raises the exception?

Comment: The only other thing I can think it might be, is if you're looking at (for example) nodeJS logs on the receiving end, are you using Nginx/Apache or similar to proxy the request? Timeout could occur there?

Comment: I'm only at the point where I'm testing it locally. Here I'm using a [pow](http://pow.cx) server, so I can run multiple apps at the same time.

Comment: It’s hard to know what’s causing it without know exactly what you’re using. I would try and test each component independently; test your receiving server outside of Ruby/HTTParty and see if the timeout still occurs, and narrow it down until you work out which part is causing it.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 did u ever find solution? Can you please share it, facing same

Comment: @Rashmi nope unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Found the solution in an issue on github:
   https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/594

The essence is that some servers could block requests that contain `ruby` in their user agent/name (which happens because "ruby" is the user agent used by httparty).

Try by specifying the user agent as such (note rby without the `u`):

```
response = HTTParty.get(my_url, headers: {"User-Agent" => "Why would you block rby agent? Come on"})
```

2. It could also be that the server has an error and really sends over incomplete data. Test it out with a server you control and can check that the response is properly formatted (proper json, not missing backticks).